# Connect wifi Printer to android device to take PDF print programatically using Printer Manager

Tags: android, pdf, printing

I want to connect my wifi printer to my android device and take print of pdf using printer manager.I have searched alot on google although there are many question like mine but i didn't got any solution .My printer is not Cloud Ready Printer.Please help.Thanks in advance...!!

Answer (score 1):

I assume u r trying to print Custom document using print manager.

The time u give print cmd a dialog appears saying "Searching for printer" indefinitely.

1. Give a test doc print from Printer and u'll get the required information to connect to the printer.
2. Well all u gotta do is download the "Plug-in" for ur printer from Play store.
3. After download u need to turn it on and connect to printer using the credentials u got in test doc print.

Now try to print a doc from ur app.

Comment: Thanks for replying..!! let me try this first.

Comment: Hii @kevz i got doc of my printer but didn't got printer wifi password although got SSID .And i need it to make connnection .Can you please help me to out.Help Appreciated..!!

Comment: @Divya SIngh: let continue in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99174/connect-wifi-printer-to-android-device-to-take-pdf-print-programatically-using-pr

Answer (score 0):

private void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {

```
    //try to make a "Bond" if possible. Else return
    if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
        try {
            createBond(device);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showToast("Failed to pair device");

            return;
        }
    }
```

private void createBond(BluetoothDevice device) throws Exception {

```
    try {
        Class<?> cl = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Class<?>[] par = {};

        Method method = cl.getMethod("createBond", par);

        method.invoke(device);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: my printer is not bluetooth device so why i have to make bond ?